# Relevance of orientation of curve to integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ be two smooth functions defined on
> $\mathbb R$. Let $S$ be a positively oriented circle of radius $1$
> around the origin. Which of the following is zero?
>
> I. $\int_S (\phi(y) + \psi(x)) \ dy$
>
> II. $\int_S \phi(xy) (ydx + xdy)$
>
> III. $\int_S \phi(x) \psi(y) \ dx$

First, I'm unsure how the fact the circle $S$ is "positively oriented" is relevant to the question.

Second, don't we require some additional information like whether $\phi(x)$, $\phi(y)$ and $\phi(xy)$ are odd or even functions (about the $x$ and $y$ axes)?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to wait till you study differential geometry and topology for a good answer to this question.

Comment: @K.defaoite I know some amount of topology and differential geometry.

Comment: What are $\psi(x)$ and $\psi(y),$ anyway?

Comment: I believe that the orientation of the curve is irrelevant. One can show that if $\mathcal C$ is oriented positively, then $-\mathcal C$ is oriented negatively, and we have that $$\oint_{-\mathcal C} \mathbf F \cdot d \mathbf r = -\oint_\mathcal C \mathbf F \cdot d \mathbf r,$$ where $\mathbf r(t)$ is the positively oriented parametrization of the curve $\mathcal C$ for $a \leq t \leq b.$ Considering that we are asking when these integrals are $0,$ the sign is not going to matter.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the vector field $\mathbf F(x, y) = \langle \phi(xy) y, \phi(xy) x \rangle.$ By hypothesis that $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ are smooth functions on $\mathbb R,$ it follows that the component functions of $\mathbf F$ have continuous first-order partial derivatives on an open region containing the unit disk $D.$ By Green's Theorem, we have that $$\int_S \phi(xy)(y \, dx + x \, dy) = \int_S (\phi(xy) y \, dx + \phi(xy) x \, dy) = \iint_D \biggl(\frac \partial {\partial x} \phi(xy) x - \frac \partial {\partial y} \phi(xy) y \biggr) \, dA.$$ By the Chain Rule, we have that $\frac \partial {\partial x} \phi(xy) x = \phi'(xy) xy + \phi(xy) = \frac \partial {\partial y} \phi(xy) y,$ hence the integrand on the right-hand side of the above displayed equation is $0,$ and the integral is $0.$

Unless more information is given, I am not sure if it can be determined that either I or III are $0.$